# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to encode parameters to be sent to a web service for processing.
I start with a command with parameters such as:

```
TransportProviderConfirmation/68,Akal Singh,+972544944860,1234
```

I pass this string to a the encoding function:

```
template = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(template);
```

The returned string is not changed in any way, despite the fact that there is a blank space which should be turned into %20, and a plus sign which should be turned into %2B. What is happening?

Comment: As the name implies, the method encodes HTML. :)
You need UrlEncode.

Answer (score 9):

HtmlEncode?  I think you're looking for [UrlEncode()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx).